# Issues regarding phpMyAdmin - character set

Tags: mysql, migration, wordpress

I'm trying to migrate a Wordpress site from one server to another. Everything is going fine apart from the database migration.

I have my database 'A', and using phpMyAdmin I am attempting to export it so that I may use phpMA on the destination server to to import it.

The problem appears to be that when I'm importing the database, it doesn't recognize the character type `utf8mb4` despite my efforts to change the character set/type in phpmyadmin to `utf8` via queries and being told that it has changed by the console.

I also ensured that UTF8 was selected on both locations and that doesn't seem to help at all. I've tried to search for help but I've been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL did not have `utf8mb4` until version 5.5.3; are both versions newer than that?

Is the exported file a text file?  If so, look in it for `utf8` and see if it says `utf8` or `utf8mb4`.

Did you use any "character set" argument on mysqldump when exporting?  What about on importing?  For *mysql* and *phpmyadmin* it needs to be utf8mb4.  For the rest of the world, `UTF-8` or maybe `UTF8`.